# Health insurance deduction on schedule C if also full time employee with w2?

Tags: taxes, health-insurance, schedule-c

I'm a full time employee of a small company that does not provide any health insurance benefits.  As a result I purchase my health insurance as an individual.  In addition to my full time work where I receive a w2 I also consult on the side and get a 1099-MISC from my client.  I earn roughly 25% of my net income from consulting.  Based on [this](https://www.irs.gov/uac/Newsroom/Dont-Miss-the-Health-Insurance-Deduction-if-Youre-Self-Employed) I understand that self employed people can deduct health insurance premiums.  Given my circumstances can I deduct health insurance premiums on a schedule C?

Comment: Yes, you can deduct against your self-employed net-profit.  Or if you're itemizing your deductions on your personal taxes you can include your medical premiums there.  https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc502.html

Comment: @quid I knew about the itemized deduction, but it needs to exceed 10% of my agi (it doesn't).  With the self-employment income it looks like I can deduct it no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the worksheet on page 20 of Pub 535.  Also the text starting in the last half of the third column of page 18 onward.

https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p535.pdf

The fact that you get a W-2 is irrelevant as far as I can see.  Your self-employment business has to meet some criteria (such as being profitable) and the plan needs to be provided through your own business (although if you're sole proprietor filing on Schedule C, it looks like having it in your own name does the trick).  Check the publication for all of the rules.

There is this exception that would prevent many people with full-time jobs on W-2 from taking the deduction:

> Other coverage. You cannot take the deduc­tion for any month you were eligible to partici­pate in any employer (including your spouse's) subsidized health plan at any time during that month, even if you did not actually participate. In addition, if you were eligible for any month or part of a month to participate in any subsidized health plan maintained by the employer of ei­ther your dependent or your child who was un­der age 27 at the end of 2014, do not use amounts paid for coverage for that month to fig­ure the deduction.

(Pages 20-21).  Sounds like in your case, though, this doesn't apply. (Although your original question doesn't mention a spouse, which might be relevant to the rule if you have one and he/she works.)

The publication should help.  If still in doubt, you'll probably need a CPA or other professional to assess your individual situation.

Answer (score 2):

Do you satisfy the necessary criteria listed there? Then why not?... It sounds like you do.

Comment: I do.  I guess I'm wondering if I still qualify since I'm not 100% self employed.  It seems strange that because I have additional income from consulting I could deduct my premiums, but if I didn't have that income I wouldn't be able to.

Comment: @Doov isn't the US tax code fun?

Comment: It works that way because employers typically make their health plan available to employees via a Section 125 cafeteria plan.  In a cafeteria plan your contributions to your coverage are deducted from your paycheck in a pre-tax manner, your employers contributions to the plan are a business expense.  So W2 employees can't deduct their costs because it was contributed tax free already.

Comment: @quid you're explaining what is happening, but it doesn't make it any less ridiculous. Why a self-employed person can deduct medical insurance pre-tax, while an employee cannot? No reason. Sec. 125 plans are not available everywhere and you saw from the outcry about the mandate to offer them imposed on larger employers - quite a lot of employers don't think they should offer them. There's no real reason for this in the tax code, just politics and narrow-minded thinking of people who just don't know any better.

Comment: @littleadv  The employee is paying for their contribution to an employer's health on a tax free basis.  Self employed folks can deduct as an expense.  W2 employees without access to an employer health plan can deduct their premium also, though some (many) won't have itemized deductions that exceed the the standard deduction.  So I'm not sure which part of this you see as a problem.

Comment: @quid *W2 employees without access to an employer health plan can deduct their premium also* - no. To answer your general question - the main problem I see is that health insurance is somehow tied to employment. I think the US is the only country in the world where in order to get health insurance coverage you must be employed. Reminiscence of slavery, I guess. Being a foreigner, it is just yet another thing that to me is incredibly unreasonable while Americans just can't see how the world could be any different.

Comment: @littleadv Slavery... spare me.

Comment: @quid sorry, forgot you Americans are all super PC...

Comment: @littleadv, this has nothing to do with PC.  That's a flatly absurd comparison.

Comment: You're an American I take it... You people just don't see it.

Comment: @quid I disagree with littleadv's more inflammatory points, but, on the narrow point of this deduction, the rule does seem arbitrary. The OP is unable to get a deduction at all (as practical matter given the limits to claiming on Sch A) without the side job but can deduct because of this extra income. It's kind of a corner case since most full-time employers do / are required to provide some insurance benefit, but it's still a strange case.

Comment: @Brick, I agree that this is an odd case.  But all tax rules are arbitrary.  Why is "affordable" employer coverage 9.5% of income?  Why is 10% of AGI meaningful for an individual deduction?  Why is my employer's portion of my employer sponsored coverage not considered taxable compensation to me?  Full time W2 employees with no access to employer healthcare are rare and dwindling; most will take the standard deduction and/or fall within the income range for subsidized coverage at an exchange, making the deduction moot.  This is all conjecture anyway because we don't know income and state.

Comment: @quid "rare and dwindling", "fall within the income range for subsidized coverage at an exchange" - that is **now**, during the last several years only. Finally, the US stepped into the 20th century. But wait, next elections the republicans win they're going to throw you back into the stone age.

Comment: @littleadv  I have no idea what point you're trying to make.  I'll be ignoring you now.

Comment: @quid just voicing my impressions of how Americans are idiots, but that's fine because otherwise I wouldn't be earning  big bucks here, right? So keep on doing what you're doing, it's good for me.